# Does using the 'this' keyword affect Java performance?

Tags: performance, java-7, java

Does using the `this` keyword affect Java performance at all?

In this example:

```
class Prog {
  private int foo;

  Prog(int foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}
```

Is there performance overhead doing that over the following?:

```
class Prog {
  private int foo;

  Prog(int bar) {
    foo = bar;
  }
}
```

A couple of coworkers and I were discussing this earlier today and no one could come up with an answer the we all agreed on. Any definitive answer?

Comment: `javap` is your friend. Unless the command line is your enemy.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, not at all. It is just a different syntax for the same thing. It gets compiled into exactly the same piece of bytecode. So say it like a human: you are telling the compiler twice exactly the same thing what to do, in two different ways.

---

`javap` proves it. Here is with the `this.`:

```
{
  Prog(int);
    flags: 
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0       
         5: iload_1       
         6: putfield      #2                  // Field foo:I
         9: return        
      LineNumberTable:
        line 4: 0
        line 5: 4
        line 6: 9
}
```

And here is without `this.`:

```
{
  Prog2(int);
    flags: 
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0       
         5: iload_1       
         6: putfield      #2                  // Field foo:I
         9: return        
      LineNumberTable:
        line 4: 0
        line 5: 4
        line 6: 9
}
```

Only difference is the `2`, but I had to choose a different name for the two test cases.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used javap before. Like @T.J. Crowder Magic said, I should probably go back to the JLS for a bit and study up on javap, too.

Comment: Was it always like this? I haven't done Java for the last 10 years or so, but I briefly remember hearing back then, that the use of this was slightly faster due to some optimizations, maybe it was a wrong assumption.

Comment: @MeTitus I heard the opposite, that using this is slightly slower :) but I am not able to find anything performance related to the usage of `this`. Therefore I consider using this as equal to not using it.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not.

The code with or without `this` keyword after compilation is exactly the same.